# how to rotate turtle shape in python

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, rotation, turtle-graphics

I registered the shape of my turtle in my roulette game to a roulette wheel. I want the wheel to spin 3 times. This is my program:

```
register_shape("wheel.gif")
wheel = None
wheel = turtle.Turtle()
wheel.ht()
wheel.shape("wheel.gif")


wheel.shapesize(5, 5)
wheel.pu()
wheel.ht()
wheel.goto(-200,-200)
wheel.st()
r = 1
for r in range(108):
    wheel.right(10)
```

The wheel shows up properly but it doesn't seem to spin. I would assume this should work. 
If not is there any other way. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with Python turtle graphics. I circumvented it by registering different images in different rotational states. Then you can use conditional statements to show a suitable image in each partcular state. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I found that this will not be possible, according to the documentation of the `register_shape()` method:

> **Note:** Image shapes do not rotate when turning the turtle, so they do
>   not display the heading of the turtle!

Reference: http://docs.python.org/library/turtle.html#turtle.register_shape

---

However, it seems that there are two other ways to use `register_shape()` which *should* provide rotation, since the above disclaimer only refers to image shapes.

1. Using coordinates to draw a polygon shape.
2. Using a compound shape object (a compound shape consists of multiple polygons).