# How to turn turtle.shape with image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

This is my code to make a rocket move around in a turtle screen:

```
import turtle
s = turtle.Screen()
image = "rocket.gif"
s.addshape(image)
turtle.shape(image)
s.bgcolor("black")

def fd():
  turtle.fd(5)

def bk():
  turtle.bk(10)

def lt():
  turtle.lt(5)

def rt():
  turtle.rt(5)

turtle.penup()
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.home()

s.listen()
s.onkeypress(fd, "Up")
s.onkeypress(bk, "Down")
s.onkeypress(lt, "Left")
s.onkeypress(rt, "Right")
```

When I press the up button the rocket moves forward, and when I press the right button, the rocket image does not turn, but when it moves forward again the direction of the movement does change.

I read this at the help() section at Python3 IDLE:

> Image shapes do not rotate when turning the turtle, so they do not display the heading of the turtle!

But, I do not understand is this for turtle.rt() or turtle.setheading()?
Even if it is for both, how do I rotate the image?

Note: Surprisingly it works with
[**trinket.io**](https://blog.trinket.io/using-images-in-turtle-programs/)

Comment: That puzzled me too at first, and I conclude that trinket took this obvious problem with turtle, about which dozens of questions have been asked in the past 5 years, and wrote a little wrapper script to accomplish the shape substitution (or perhaps even on-demand rotation) which stays behind the scenes and which the user does not see.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to rotate turtle shape in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277518/how-to-rotate-turtle-shape-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

We can make a shape appear to rotate by telling a turtle to switch between different related shapes.
use **setshape (setsh) and setheading (seth)**.For more details Visit  http://mia.openworldlearning.org/howdoi/ftn.htm

Comment: I would like to know how to make the turtle turn any number of degrees. But for that, I do not think 360 images would be efficient

Answer (score 0):

Try using Numpy to semi-automatically generate 256 dirction spritepacks.(You can do this by saving a image like this:
pxr pxr pxy
pxw pxr pxn
pxr pxr pxn
into

```
[[pxr,pxr,pxy],
[pxw,pxr,pxn],
[pxr,pxr,pxn]]
```

then using calculations to slant the pixels, so for degree 1 it slants right 1 pixel every 64 pixls,for degree 2 it slants right 2 pixelx every 64 pixls, so on